# jQuery plugin installation (overlay effect)

Tags: jquery

i need some help, i found below jQuery plugin but not much info on how to install it, can anyone enlighten me? Thank you.

http://ryun.github.io/HCaptions/

Comment: Simply add the js file in your project. Include the js in script tag in your file and use the way they have showed you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to follow below steps

1) Download code or clone code from [github repository](https://github.com/ryun/HCaptions)

2) Add this library in you project folder

3) Add Javascript library file and jQuery file into your HTML code

```
<script src="path of jQuery file" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="path of library file" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

4) Apply library as per document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(selector).hcaptions({
      effect: "slide",
      speed: "1000"
   });
});
</script>
```